# Trying to retrieve data and then add one on the max string (int-string conversions)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio

So I'm trying to take data from a database (patientid in the format pXX) and when I add a new patient to the database through the website it automatically finds the max patient id and then adds 1 to it. So if the max patient id is p12 it makes the new patient p13.

What I've done so far is; isolate two numbers in a string (using sub string method), convert them to an int, find the max number, convert back to a string, test if the string length is smaller then 2, add 1 zero to it, and then I added a p. This is my code;

```
    public void patientInsert()
    {
        hospitalSQLEntities db = new hospitalSQLEntities();
        int newid = 0;
        string mynumberstring = "patientid".Substring(1, 2);
        int patientid1 = Convert.ToInt32(mynumberstring);
        string p = "p";
        if (db.patients.Count() == 0)
            newid = 1;
        else
            newid = db.patients.Max(u => patientid1) + 1;
            newid = Convert.ToString(newid);
            newid = newid < 2, + "0"; 
            newid = (p + patientid1);
        patient newpatient = new patient();
        newpatient.patientid = Convert.ToString(Request.Params["newid"]);
        newpatient.doctorno = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Params["doctorno"]);
        newpatient.wardno = Request.Params["wardno"];
        newpatient.patientname = Request.Params["patientname"];
        newpatient.address = Request.Params["address"];
        newpatient.gender = Request.Params["gender"];
        newpatient.bloodtype = Request.Params["bloodtype"];
        newpatient.spam = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Params["spam"]);
        newpatient.organs = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Params["organs"]);
        db.AddTopatients(newpatient);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Am I doing this right? I know I'm tripping up in the conversion from int to string and again on adding the 0 and the p but I'm just a bit lost.

p.s. first time trying to program so go easy if it's a silly mistake!

Comment: Why is the id a string instead of any kind of number in the database? Is this an existing database you have to deal with or did you design it yourself? If you can change it, make it a number. This way it is sortable. Those "pXX" strings are not really numerically sortable, but only alphabetically. If you have over thousands of entries they will be sorted like: ... p0 p1 p10 p100 p1000 p1001 and so on. That is not what you want. Fetching all entries and converting them to numbers only to sort them isnt a very good solution either...

Comment: Yeah I know the database is badly designed but that's the one we have to use. I was thinking I'd only fetch the max patient id and just add 1 to it but am a bit unsure on how to do it.

Comment: If you calculate the new patient id like this, won't you risk a PK violation if another user saves a new patient between the time you read the database and the time you call `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @adrift: Yes, thats another point that speaks against this db design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, instead of storing the patientid as PXX, I would just store the XX (in the database, just store the integer.  If they all have a P in the beginning, that would just be a display issue (show a P and any needed leading zeros - only when displaying it).  If you do this, then the database could even handle the numbering for you (in SQL Server, its called an `IDENTITY` field).

Second, here is how I would change your code - this is not to make it work, just to show you some mistakes

(NOTE: I put a comment of "`LOOK HERE`" where changes were made)

```
public void patientInsert()
{
    hospitalSQLEntities db = new hospitalSQLEntities();
    int newid = 0;
    //LOOK HERE: "patientid" - removed quotes (assuming patientid is a variable)
    //LOOK HERE: Substring - removed second parameter (isn't needed, and anyway, once you get higher than 100, you'll need to change your code from 2 to 3)
    string mynumberstring = patientid.Substring(1);
    int patientid1 = Convert.ToInt32(mynumberstring);
    //LOOK HERE: removed p variable (too simple - waste of space)
    //string p = "p";
    if (db.patients.Count() == 0)
    {
        newid = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //LOOK HERE: are you trying to get the max id from the database?  if so, then this wont work. you need something like this:
        //newid = db.patients.Max(u => patientid1) + 1;
        newid = db.patients.Max(u => Int32.Parse(u.patientid.Substring(1))) + 1;
        //LOOK HERE: newid is defined as int. It can't be changed to string.
        //newid = Convert.ToString(newid);
        //newid = newid < 2, + "0"; 
        //newid = (p + patientid1);
    }
    patient newpatient = new patient();
    //LOOK HERE: newid is a variable, not a page parameter
    //newpatient.patientid = Convert.ToString(Request.Params["newid"]);
    //LOOK HERE: Look at String.format - this is your key to the leading zeros
    newpatient.patientid = String.Format("P{0:00}", newid);
    newpatient.doctorno = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Params["doctorno"]);
    newpatient.wardno = Request.Params["wardno"];
    newpatient.patientname = Request.Params["patientname"];
    newpatient.address = Request.Params["address"];
    newpatient.gender = Request.Params["gender"];
    newpatient.bloodtype = Request.Params["bloodtype"];
    newpatient.spam = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Params["spam"]);
    newpatient.organs = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Params["organs"]);
    db.AddTopatients(newpatient);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for that, it was really helpful. But I think we'd still have a problem with;

int patientid1 = Convert.ToInt32(mynumberstring);

I thought you would have to write extra parameters?

Comment: I have no clue why you would need the variable patientid1 anymore. What was it meant to do in your code? In the code from Gabriel McAdams, it isnt needed anymore. In his code he does basically two important things: He searches for the biggest existing patient id with ``db.patients.Max(u => Int32.Parse(u.patientid.Substring(1)))``, increments this number by one and takes this to form the new id by calling ``String.Format("P{0:00}", newid)``. That was it. That is all that is needed for this task.

Comment: O right I see, sorry I was just having a reading through an it struck me as unusual with my limited programming knowledge. Sorry for the naivety! I see how it works now. Thanks heaps :)

Comment: @Rachel - I left that in to show you the errors you had.  Philip is right. It is not needed any longer.  Sorry for not finishing the code - I didn't want to do all the work for you, just to help you along.